# WordPress Admin Menu customization

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, menu, admin

I'm trying to customize my WordPress Admin Menu by preventing sub-items to show to the right sliding them down instead. It works but doesn't slide down overlays other items as you can see in the image:

[image]

js code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Collapse inactive menu items initially
    $('#adminmenu li.menu-top:not(.wp-has-current-submenu):not(:hover)').find('.wp-submenu').hide();

    // Expand and collapse menu items on click
    $('#adminmenu li.menu-top').click(function() {
        var $submenu = $(this).find('.wp-submenu');

        if (!$submenu.is(':visible')) {
            // Collapse other open submenus
            $('#adminmenu li.menu-top .wp-submenu').not($submenu).slideUp();

            // Expand clicked submenu
            $submenu.slideDown();
        }
    });
});

function disableSubMenuSlide() {
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#adminmenu li.menu-top').hover(function() {
            $(this).find('ul').css({
                right: 'auto',
                opacity: 1,
                visibility: 'visible'
            });
        });
    });
}

// Call the function
disableSubMenuSlide();
```

CSS code:

```
#adminmenu .wp-has-current-submenu .wp-submenu {
    display: block;
    width: 160px;
    border: 0;
}

/* Disable slide behavior for sub-menu items */
#adminmenu li.menu-top:hover > ul {
    right: auto;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Hpw to solve this?

I want the menu to slide down sub-items instead of slide right on click!

Comment: « It works but doesn't slide down overlays other items as you can see in the image« I think this sentence misses some punctuation. Or please explain what doesn’t slide down overlays other items?